# Show that if matrix $A$ is symmetric, then so is $P^TAP$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to show that if $A$ is symmetric, then so is $P^TAP$, assuming the matrix multiplications are valid.

I'm sure if I actually expanded the matrices to show the entries and did the multiplication, I would be able to show this is true, however, that would be quite the process and I'm certain there is a better way. Unfortunately, I've been unable to come up with a better way to show the statement is true.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try taking $(P^{T}AP)^{T}$, and see what you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you already proved that
$$(AB)^T=B^T A^T$$
you have
$$(P^T A P)^T=P^T A^T P^{TT}=P^T A P$$
since A is symmetric and double transposition is the identity.

Comment: I feel incredibly silly. I've been staring at $P^TA^TP$ for quite a while now and it didn't even click that $A^T = A$. Thank you everybody who gave the right hints.

Comment: Don't worry, it's one of those tricks you learn once and then use almost on a daily basis, we've all been through that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Remember that $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$ for any compatible matrices $A,B$.